# MySQL query error -unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My query string is

```
$chk_cookie="SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client=5279f0addc835 AND cookie_data=3";
 $chk_query=mysql_query($chk_cookie) or die(mysql_error());
```

this give the error unknown column.
if I put ' in value

```
'5279f0addc835'
```

It gives check manual for syntax error.

If I remove first condition i.e uniqid_client=5279f0addc835 then it runs normally.
If I do string like

```
$chk_cookie="SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client=".5279f0addc835." AND cookie_data=3";
 or
 $chk_cookie="SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client='".5279f0addc835."' AND cookie_data=3";
```

It gives the same check manual error....
Another thing if I run it on phpMyAdmin SQL it gives the desired result
what should I do ...I am not able to get error...
5279f0addc835 value I have created by php uniqid() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accepting all the answer but i thing should check your database data type and table data.if you have wrong datatype and blank field then it will give error.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$chk_cookie="SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client='5279f0addc835' AND cookie_data=3";
```

Comment: You bet me by 2 seconds ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose **`uniqid_client=5279f0addc835`** in single quotes as it is a **`VARCHAR`** type. Something like this

```
$chk_cookie="SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client='5279f0addc835' AND cookie_data=3";
 $chk_query=mysql_query($chk_cookie) or die(mysql_error());
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Comment: You tried `".5279f0addc835."`. Try this like i have shown in my answer. `'5279f0addc835'`

Comment: Can you post the query here ?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM cookie_data_mst WHERE uniqid_client='5279f0addc835' AND cookie_data=3"